# .htaccess multiviews not workinng in Control Web Panel server

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, web, centos-web-panel

I had a running php web application previously hosted using cpanel. Now I have shifted it to Control Web panel(CWP) for hosting . But the multiviews and error handling I managed using .htaccess file is not being responded by the server so that I need to add .php behind every links now. Is there any solution for it?
My .htaccess file:

```
    Options +MultiViews
    DefaultType application/x-httpd-php

    Options -Indexes
    ErrorDocument 403 /403
    ErrorDocument 404 /404
```

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitely read the docs at [httpd.apache.org](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/core.html#defaulttype) and not rely on control panels or try and error.

`DefaultType` was a fallback directive, is deprecated and has been disabled. It was never meant to activate interpreters.

You are looking for [SetHandler](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/core.html#sethandler):

```
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
```

This should activate PHP processing for every file on the server, as long as mod_php is loaded, including images, downloads and everything else.

Maybe you want to use something like this instead:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .htm .html
```

It will restrict PHP to those extensions only.

Everything on MultiViews is a part of [Content Negotiation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html).